# How to extract data from a JSON file into a variable

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sh

I have the following json format, basically it is a huge file with several of such entries.

```
 [
      {
        "id": "kslhe6em",
        "version": "R7.8.0.00_BNK",
        "hostname": "abacus-ap-hf-test-001:8080",
        "status": "RUNNING",
           },
      {
        "id": "2bkaiupm",
        "version": "R7.8.0.00_BNK",
        "hostname": "abacus-ap-hotfix-001:8080",
        "status": "RUNNING",
      },
      {
        "id": "rz5savbi",
        "version": "R7.8.0.00_BNK",
        "hostname": "abacus-ap-hf-test-005:8080",
        "status": "RUNNING",
          },
          
    ]
```

I wanted to fetch all the hostname values that starts with "abacus-ap-hf-test"  and without ":8080" into a variable and then wanted to use those values for further commands over a for loop something like below. But, am bit confused how can I extract such informaion.

```
HOSTAME="abacus-ap-hf-test-001 abacus-ap-hf-test-005"
for HOSTANAME in $HOSTNAME
do 
  sh ./trigger.sh
done
```

Comment: duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/725744/4667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line command update to this:

```
HOSTAME=$(grep -oP 'hostname": "\K(abacus-ap-hf-test[\w\d-]+)' json.file)
```

or if you sure that the hostname end with **:8080"**, try this:

```
HOSTAME=$(grep -oP '(?<="hostname": ")abacus-ap-hf-test[\w\d-]+(?=:8080")' json.file)
```

you will find that `abacus-ap-hf-test[\w\d-]+` is the regex, and other strings are the head or the end of the regex content which for finding result accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have valid JSON, you can get the hostname values using `jq`:

```
while read -r hname ; do  printf "%s\n" "$hname" ; done < <(jq -r .[].hostname j.json)
```

Output:

```
abacus-ap-hf-test-001:8080
abacus-ap-hotfix-001:8080
abacus-ap-hf-test-005:8080
```